# "Device or resource busy" while adding vlan using vconfig

Tags: linux, networking

It has been two days but not getting any clue why I am getting "vconfig: ioctl error for add: Device or resource busy" error while configuring VLAN.

Checklist:

1. Port is up
2. Port is not the part of any bridge.

Below is the strace of the command but not getting much pointer for this problem:

```
# strace vconfig add port00 100

execve("/usr/sbin/vconfig", ["vconfig", "add", "port00", "100"], 0xffcb640c /* 7 vars */) = 0
readlinkat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/self/exe", "/usr/bin/busybox", 4096) = 16
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|1<<MAP_HUGE_SHIFT, -1, 0) = 0xf77b0000
open("/lib//libc.so.0", O_RDONLY)       = 7
fstat(7, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0775, st_size=653404, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|1<<MAP_HUGE_SHIFT, -1, 0) = 0xf77af000
read(7, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\3\0\1\0\0\0P\1\1\0004\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 4096
mmap2(NULL, 753664, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xf76f7000
mmap2(0xf76f7000, 647324, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED, 7, 0) = 0xf76f7000
mmap2(0xf7796000, 4990, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED, 7, 0x9e000) = 0xf7796000
mmap2(0xf7798000, 91824, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xf7798000
close(7)                                = 0
munmap(0xf77af000, 4096)                = 0
stat("/lib/ld-uClibc.so.0", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0775, st_size=25388, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|1<<MAP_HUGE_SHIFT, -1, 0) = 0xf77af000
set_thread_area({entry_number=-1, base_addr=0xf77af690, limit=0x0fffff, seg_32bit=1, contents=0, read_exec_only=0, limit_in_pages=1, seg_not_present=0, useable=1}) = 0 (entry_number=12)
gettimeofday({tv_sec=1595835665, tv_usec=909210}, NULL) = 0
mprotect(0x80c4000, 4096, PROT_READ)    = 0
mprotect(0xf7796000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0xf77b7000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
set_tid_address(0xf77af6f8)             = 16103
set_robust_list(0xf77af6fc, 12)         = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRTMIN, {sa_handler=0xf775abdb, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, sa_restorer=0xf7708eed}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_1, {sa_handler=0xf775aaf8, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, sa_restorer=0xf7708eed}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [RTMIN RT_1], NULL, 8) = 0
ugetrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM_INFINITY}) = 0
uname({sysname="Linux", nodename="EAGLE-ECE555F60000", ...}) = 0
ioctl(0, TCGETS, {B115200 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(1, TCGETS, {B115200 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
getuid32()                              = 0
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 7
ioctl(7, SIOCSIFVLAN, 0xffb0ceb4)       = -1 EBUSY (Device or resource busy)
write(2, "vconfig: ioctl error for add: De"..., 54vconfig: ioctl error for add: Device or resource busy
) = 54
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
#
```

Answer (score 0):

[vconfig](https://linux.die.net/man/8/vconfig#:%7E:text=The%20vconfig%20program%20allows%20you,lans%20on%20the%20physical%20lan.) is a virtual ethernet configuration program. [TCGETS](https://linux.die.net/man/4/tty_ioctl) (in the stack trace) is a tty (teletype terminal) configuration - i.e. serial port settings (hence the B115200 (baud rate 115200 in your strace). In other words, you are trying to configure a serial port as a vlan port. Are you sure you want to be doing that ? What is the device that port00 refers to ?

Comment: No, port00 is not the serial port, port00 is the physical interface in our device. Except this port00 two more ports are there i.e port01 and port02. 

One observation that I want to share here is that there is one more virtual interface eth0 that is the "bridge interface" and all the physical interface ( port00, port01 and port02) are the part of that virtual interface eth0. When we create vlan on that virtual interface eth0, it works fine. 

PS: Before creating vlan on port00, I removed port00 interafce from eth0 bridge.

Also, I am getting same baud rate in success scenario as well.

Comment: yeah, so if you look at the vconfig man page, to create a virtual interface using *vconfig add* you can only do that on a real physical interface. If your "port00" doesn't come up in *ip link show* then you can't specify it as the interface in vconfig add. I suspect your port00 doesn't match a real interface and so vconfig is trying to default set it up as a serial port.

Comment: No, port00 is real interface not virtual one. 
Also, it is showing in "ip link show" command.

Comment: in that case its worth checking if something else is referencing port00, i.e. if some program has an open file descriptor on it. Removing it from any bridge may not be enough, something else could have it open.